# Регулярное выражение в методе replace();

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код

```
image = "url(/путь/до/изображения)"
```

Нужно у пути обрезать `"url()"` чтобы получилось `/путь/до/изображения`
Я решил использовать `image.replace(/"url\(/g,'').replace(/)"/g,'')`, но на выходе почему то все равно получаю `"url(/путь/до/изображения)"`

Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри. Во-первых, кавычки у тебя — не часть строки (по крайней мере там, где ты показал). Во-вторых, не используй того, чего не знаешь (по крайней мере по этому примеру). Вот твое решение:

```
image.replace(/url\(/,'').replace(/\)/,'')
```

Флаг `g` отвечает за то, чтобы найти все совпадения в строке, иначе только 1 соответствие.

Да, и на самом деле, зачем тебе регулярное выражение? Запроси напрямую:

```
image.replace('url(','').replace(')','')
```

Comment: `.replace(/\)/,'')` зачем так все усложнять, чтобы скобку удалить? :)